# Collision in Phaser Box2D

Tags: box2d, collision, phaser-framework

Does somebody know how to identify a rectangle within a body?

Example:

```
this.myBody = new Phaser.Physics.Box2D.Body(this.game, null, 10, 10);
this.myBody.addRectangle(2, 10, 10 * Math.cos(60), 10 * Math.sin(60), 60);
this.myBody.addRectangle(2, 10, 10 * Math.cos(60), 10 * Math.sin(60), 60);
```

If an object did collide with the body containing the rectangles, how can I know that rectangle collision made the object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a rectangle to a body in Box2D, you're adding a fixture. We can identify a fixture by its id.

```
this.myBody = new Phaser.Physics.Box2D.Body(this.game, null, 10, 10);
var fixture1 = this.myBody.addRectangle(2, 10, 10 * Math.cos(60), 10 * Math.sin(60), 60);
this.rect1_id = fixture1.id;
var fixture2 = this.myBody.addRectangle(2, 10, 10 * Math.cos(60), 10 * Math.sin(60), 60);
this.rect2_id = fixture2.id;
```

Then, we can add a collision callback to the sprite. This will be called whenever the body collides with another body in that category. Make sure to set the category of bodies.

```
this.onCollision = function(thisBody, theirBody, thisFixture, theirFixture, begin, contact) {
    // Parameters are:
    // thisBody: the body of the sprite
    // theirBody: the body of the sprite 'thisBody' collided with
    // thisFixture, theirFixture: the fixtures of the bodies that collided
    // begin: whether this was the start of the collision
    // contact: the collision object

    // I'll define what goes in this below
};

var category = 11;
this.body.setCollisionCategory(1);
this.body.setCollisionMask(1);
this.body.setCategoryContactCallback(
  category,
  this.onCollision,
  this
);
```

Finally, this.onCollision is called, we can just check the fixture's id and compare it to the values we've stored in this.rect1_id and this.rect2_id.

```
this.onCollision = function(thisBody, theirBody, thisFixture, theirFixture, begin, contact) {
    switch (thisFixture.id) {
    case this.rect1_id:
        console.log('hit the first rectangle!');
        break;
    case this.rect2_id:
        console.log('hit the second rectangle!);
        break;
    default:
        console.log("I don't recognise this fixture.");
    }
};
```

Sorry this response is 2 years old! I've found it while looking for something else.